# How to find a string that match a substring in any order?

Tags: python, string, list, substring

Assuming a list as follows:

```
list_of_strings = ['foo', 'bar', 'soap', 'seo', 'paseo', 'oes']
```

and a sub string

```
to_find = 'eos'
```

I would like to find the string(s) in the `list_of_strings` that match the sub string. The output from the `list_of_strings` should be `['seo', 'paseo', 'oes']` (since it has all the letters in the `to_find` sub string)

I tried a couple of things:

```
a = next((string for string in list_of_strings if to_find in string), None) # gives NoneType object as output
```

&

```
result = [string for string in list_of_strings if to_find in string] # gives [] as output
```

but both the codes don't work.

Can someone please tell me what is the mistake I am doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem logically is comparing the *set* of characters in the word to find against the *set* of characters in each word in the list.  If the latter word contains all characters in the word to find, then it is a match.  Here is one approach using a list comprehension along with set `intesection`:

```py
list_of_strings = ['foo', 'bar', 'soap', 'seo', 'paseo', 'oes']
to_find = 'eos'
to_find_set = set(list(to_find))
output = [x for x in list_of_strings if len(to_find_set.intersection(set(list(x)))) == len(to_find_set)]
print(output)  # ['seo', 'paseo', 'oes']
```

If you want to retain an empty string placeholder for any input string which does *not* match, then use this version:

```py
output = [x if len(to_find_set.intersection(set(list(x)))) == len(to_find_set) else '' for x in list_of_strings]
print(output)  # ['', '', '', 'seo', 'paseo', 'oes']
```

Comment: Set will match also ones not in order. Like "seabcdo"

Comment: @h4z3 ... and the OP clearly wants matches which are in _any_ order.

Comment: Hm... I understood any order of to_find but still a substring (letters of to_find should be next to each other) as OP used "substring" word a lot. But it seems OP said "since it has all the letters in the to_find", so your solution matches that...

Comment: `[w for w in l if to_find_set.issubset(w)]`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the help. Just one question: If no strings are available that match the `to_find`, how can I return an empty string?

Comment: @reinhardt Check the updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the letters of to_find to be next to each other or just all the letters should be in the word? Basically: does `seabco` match or not?

[Your question does not include this detail and you use "substring" a lot but also "since it has all the letters in the to_find", so I'm not sure how to interpret it.]

If `seabco` matches, then @Tim Biegeleisen's answer is the correct one. If the letters need to be next to each other (but in any order, of course), then look below:

---

If the `to_find` is relatively short, you can just generate all permutations of letters (`n!` of them, so here (3!) = 6: eos, eso, oes, ose, seo, soe) and check `in`.

```py
import itertools
list_of_strings = ['foo', 'bar', 'soap', 'seo', 'paseo', 'oes']
to_find = 'eos'

result = [string for string in list_of_strings if any("".join(perm) in string for perm in itertools.permutations(to_find))]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

We do `"".join(perm)` because perm is a tuple and we need a string.

```py
>>> result = [string for string in list_of_strings if any("".join(perm) in string for perm in itertools.permutations(to_find))]
>>> result
['seo', 'paseo', 'oes']
```

---

Less-obvious but better complexity would be to just get 3-character substrings of our strings (to keep them next to each other) and set-compare them to set of to_find.

```py
list_of_strings = ['foo', 'bar', 'soap', 'seo', 'paseo', 'oes']
to_find = 'eos'

result = [string for string in list_of_strings if any(set(three_substring)==set(to_find) for three_substring in zip(string, string[1:], string[2:]))]
```

Comment: What happens if `to_find` is large? Any alternate solution for that to improve time complexity?

Comment: I guess I'd try to do something like... zipping the original list into groups of 3s (so that we keep them next to each other) and set-comparing them (to have any order) with pattern. It's less obvious but should have better complexity, something like `O(length of list_of_strings * max length of a string in there)`